# How to specify a context.xml in the projects xml in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, maven

How can I specify a mongo-context.xml in the projects configuration in eclipse. I need maven to find that file when it builds. It was on the eclipse's classpath. However, now as eclipse is not working there is no way I can build the project through eclipse.I need to build it from the maven command line.

mongo-context.xml is used for configuring the mongodb related stuff. In my current eclipse springs project the mongo-context.xml lies in the Project/resources folder. However, when I build the same project from the command line maven cannot find the mongo-context.xml file so it does not include it in the generated war. How, do I configure that file so that maven finds it when I do a mvn clean install from the command line ?

Comment: What is *mongo-context.xml* supposed to do ? Could you describe your setup and your intentions more clearly ?

Comment: If the file needs to be on the class path root (eg: `<war_root>/WEB-INF/classes/mongo-context.xml`) then place it on `<source_root>/src/main/resources/mongo-context.xml`